# Installing Apache Stanbol through Maven

Tags: apache, maven, installation

Following the official documentation on **stanbol.apache.org**,
I can't get Apache Stanbol to work.

---

### Infra Configuration:

**OS:** Ubuntu 16.04
**JDK version:** 8
**Application server:** Tomcat 7
**Deployment node :** Digital Ocean droplet

**Query:**

What are the correct installation commands to ssuccessfully build every module , as I've managed to bypass testing phases (maven) and I've got like 8 module to build (however I can't configure them because of a security error that relates to java "access denied").

> **PS:**
>
> I've followed **the official github** repo notes on installing stanbol , however:
> I get a Security error popping out whenever I try to configure any module built while dodging tests,saying :

---

```
"access denied " along with some java security error
```

Comment: OK... what is the link to the documentation you followed, what is the OS and version of the tools involved (OS, maven, Apache Stanbol), what is the output you see?

Comment: it's the official documentation provided on the website , actually I've managed to get it to work , well parts of it at least, by dodging the testing phase .. however there is very valuable modules that aren't loaded into the war file and I need those.
The OS is ubuntu 16 , nothing special about it.
I'm deploying to tomcat 7 and building through JDK8

Comment: "it's the official documentation provided on the website": as an asker, shouldn't you put that link in your question?

Comment: https://stanbol.apache.org/

Comment: Right, but which part of https://stanbol.apache.org/docs/trunk/ were you following without being getting Stanbol to work?

Comment: Well after quite a number of tries that failed , I've switched to a more updated source:

https://github.com/apache/stanbol

Comment: OK. sorry to not be able to help more: I still don't have enough detail in your question (that you can edit) to start.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176120/discussion-between-hichem-al-abbessi-and-vonc).

Comment: Sorry, chat is blocked at work. Simply edit your question with more details, and other Stanbolt specialists will be able to help.

Comment: No need for comments; you can add everything in your question.